# Android - Empty constructor for a class also give error

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I inherited a class from another class and first I failed to give the empty constructor.But after writing an empty constructor,my application still gives the same error.

Error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.test3.VideoRecorder; no empty constructor
```

Here is the normal constructor which I am using and this works fine:

```
public Videoplanner(Context ctxt, String logTag,Application app) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
{
    super(ctxt, logTag);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] digest = digester.digest(telephonyManager.getDeviceId().getBytes());
    hashedID = (new BigInteger(1, digest)).toString(16);
    serviceName = hashedID;
    context = ctxt;
    appl = app;

}
```

Now the error comes with empty constructor which gives the error

```
public Videoplanner() 
{
    super(null, null);

}
```

I also tried with

```
 static Context context;
 static String str;

 public Videoplanner()
 {
      super(context,str);
 }
```

But this still gives me the same error.Can somebody please help?

Comment: Your error mentions `VideoRecorder`, but you are showing code for `Videoplanner`. Are you sure you are modifying the correct class?

Comment: Mistake.The error was in the class which inherits this subclass.Corrected.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you create any custom `constructor` in class then `Compiler` does not provide default empty `constructor`. In that case you have to provide empty `constructor` if you want to create `Object` of that class with no-argument `constructor`.

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
>   must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.
>   This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
>   superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
>   superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
>   that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
>   implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
>   constructor.

Reference [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)